# jquery loop progress display

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

I want to display the progress of a loop function like this '1 of total 1000'. I use this code, but in `#mycontent` article displayed only the last value of `i`.

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i += 1) {
  $('#mycontent article').html(i + ' of total 1000');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mycontent">
  <article></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you're overwriting the content with each iteration and the loop is just really fast that you don't really see the first results, only the last one.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single-threaded.  In this case that means this loop will run to completion before the UI updates, so the UI will only ever see the last change.

Taking a step back... How visually fast do you *want* the UI to update?  Even if the UI were updating, this would be *so fast* that it wouldn't really matter.  How about an interval of, say, 10ms?  The keyword there is "interval", as you can use `setInterval` to achieve this.  For example:

```js
let i = 1;
let interval = setInterval(function () {
  $('#mycontent article').html(i + ' of total 1000');
  i++;
  if (i > 1000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycontent"><article></article></div>
```

Comment: I'm scratching my head a bit about the first paragraph of your answer. Single threaded, yes of course. But the loop isn't running to completion before updating the UI. It's just happening so quickly that it's virtually impossible to see without intervention. You can append or log the values and clearly see them individually.

Comment: @j08691: My (potentially over-simplified) understanding is that the UI can't update until the thread is free.  For example, consider what happens when adding something more computationally expensive in the loop: https://jsfiddle.net/j25Lztnf/  There's a noticeable amount of time between executing the code and observing the result, and during that time the outer loop would be repeating at a consistent rate and calling `.html()` to queue a UI update each moment.  But no UI updates are seen because the thread continues to be busy...

Comment: @j08691: ... After that time it's possible that all of the updates are processed imperceptibly quickly (if there's no optimization in place to only process the last relevant one), if that's what you're referring to.  We could be talking about the same thing but just from different perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of your code is blocked until the loop finishes - therefore you see only the last value.
A JavaScript interval might be used, but instead of `setInterval` or `setTimeout` you might use the **preferred [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)** (for smoother animation and performance):

```js
const ease = {
  linear: t => t,
  inOutQuad: t => t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t,
  // Find out more at: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
};

const counter = (EL) => {

  const duration = 4000;

  const start = parseInt(EL.textContent, 10); // Get start and end values
  const end = parseInt(EL.dataset.counter, 10); // PS: Use always the radix 10!

  if (start === end) return; // If equal values, stop here.

  const range = end - start; // Get the range
  let curr = start; // Set current at start position
  
  const timeStart = Date.now();

  const loop = () => {
    let elaps = Date.now() - timeStart;
    if (elaps > duration) elaps = duration; // Stop the loop
    const norm = ease.inOutQuad(elaps / duration); // normalised value + easing
    const step = norm * range; // Calculate the value step
    curr = start + step; // Increment or Decrement current value
    EL.textContent = Math.trunc(curr); // Apply to UI as integer
    if (elaps < duration) requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Loop
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Start the loop!
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-counter]").forEach(counter);
```

```html
<span data-counter="1000">0</span> of total 1000
```

Also, you don't need JavaScript, (well as soon as Firefox implements this) - it can be done in pure CSS with `@property` and `counter`:

```css
@property --from {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.counter {
  transition: --from 1s;
  counter-reset: int var(--from);
  animation: counter var(--time, 1000) forwards ease-in-out;
}

.counter::after {
  content: counter(int) " of total 1000";
}

@keyframes counter {
  to {
    --from: var(--to, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="counter" style="--from:0; --to:1000; --time:4s;"></span>
```